# Adding CLLocationDistances

Tags: ios, swift, core-location

I'm trying to add CLLocationDistances and getting strange results. Here is my code:

```
var locations = [CLLocation]()
var totalDistance = CLLocationDistance()

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    self.locations.append(locations.first!)
    if self.locations.count > 1 {
        self.calculateTotalDistance()
    }
}

func calculateTotalDistance() -> CLLocationDistance {
    var y = 0
    self.totalDistance = 0
    while y < (locations.count - 1) {
        let firstLocation = self.locations[y]
        let secondLocation = self.locations[y + 1]
        let distance = firstLocation.distanceFromLocation(secondLocation)
        print(distance)
        totalDistance += distance
        y++
    }
    self.updateLabelWithText()
    return totalDistance
}

private func updateLabelWithText() {
    let distance = String(self.totalDistance)
    let message = "Distance in meters: " + distance
    self.distanceTextLabel.text = message
}
```

Essentially, every time I get a new CLLocation object from the system, I append it to my array. Then I iterate through the array, and get the distance between each individual points, and then add them together. I am testing the code on an actual device. As of now, when I run this code, even when I just sit down, the totalDistance variable reaches a count of 100 or so in 10 seconds, despite me not having moved anywhere close to 100 meters.

Also, in the calculateTotalDistance function, I print the distance calculated, and the distances don't seem right at all. Here is an example of what was printed to the console after the app launched for a few seconds:

```
0.0
1.15645918113224
1.06166528806247
1.06006756503664
1.05847219105153
16.1407724137949
9.67662215264722
0.0
1.15645918113224
1.06166528806247
1.06006756503664
1.05847219105153
16.1407724137949
9.6766221526472
```

Again, these are values just from when I'm sitting down, so I'm obviously not moving 16 meters, or 9 meters at a time.

Any idea what i'm doing wrong here?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is because of accuracy of GPS. Check `horizontalAccuracy` of CLLocation before adding it to array. 
You should also set `desiredAccuracy` of `CLLocationManger` to `kCLLocationAccuracyBest`.

Comment: the desired accuracy is KCLLocationAccuracyBest.

Comment: Check horizontalAccuracy of CLLocation. If it's less than threshold you require, discard it.